# Getting data from http call before loading UI

Tags: angular

I have a service that needs to populate some data with a few http calls (in this case I am fetching data from google sheets). I have several UI components that rely in data from the HTTP call to display. But the data arrives a second or two after display.

I've tried using Promise's but I think I'm not sure where to apply them. Also tried to use a Resolver but data is still loaded late.

I've got a [simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsheets-loading?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). The data.provider makes the async http call. The data.service stores the data locally. The data.resolver attempts to load the data into the service.

Not clear to me how to load the data and display it here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dustin i think your sample is wrong. You are not rendering via router outlet. I forked your [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsheets-loading-176lgc)

Comment: Thanks Eldar. Your example helped me understand my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You can use structural directive `*ngIf` to show your component when data is loaded:

TypeScript:

```
data = []

getData() { 
    this.http.GetData(params)
        .subscribe(resp =>{
            this.data = resp;
         });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="data && data.length > 0 ">   
    {{ data | json }}
</div>
```

Comment: this might be the simplist answer. I'll probably use this but I need to understand how to properly use callbacks in this case

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that http call is async, but your data-resolver method is sync. You should rewrite your data resolver to return Observable> in loadData() method. Like this:

```
    public loadData(): Observable<Array<MyData>> {

return this.getHTTPData(this.sheetId, this.tabId).pipe(
  map((resp) => {
    if (resp !== null) {
      return this.transformData(next);
    }
    return [];
  })
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **route resolver**, which allows you to get data before navigating to the new route

Create a resolver

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class YourResolver implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {
 constructor() {}

 resolve() {
   return this.yourService.getData();
 }
}
```

then the routing config

```
{
 path: '/route',
 component: resolverComponent,
 resolve: { message: YourResolver }
}
```

and then you can access the resolved data using the data property of ActivatedRoute’s snapshot object in your resolverComponent

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.data = this.route.snapshot.data;
 console.log(this.data.message);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that in the code. My resolver gets called, but the component attempts to load the UI before the data is there resulting in an error.

Comment: hii dustin have you subscribe data into component ?
let me know what you have done?